# How is traversal of a finite tree using a deque called?

Tags: search, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, deque

I have a finite tree, with its root node already on a deque. New nodes I always add to the end of the deque. I start traversing the tree by popping from the end of the deque, which is usual for a DFS algorithm. However, always, when I have visited a leaf of the tree, I pop the next node from the front of the deque, as you would do in a BFS algorithm. This means that after I have visited a leaf I will always continue with a node on the lowest (not completely explored) level of the tree (leafs are on higher levels). After visiting this node (and if this node is not a leaf) I switch back to popping from the end of the deque.

Now, let's assume that for the DFS part I do a post-order search (and a level-order for the BFS part); does the resulting search order from my algorithm have a particular well established name?

Comment: I think posting code [mre] would make your question clearer.

Comment: That's some form of progressive sampling or exploration-greedy traversal. It's probably useful for some sort of spatial queries, e.g. playing Battleship. Can you share what it will be used for?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question, maybe some code examples would help? In the mean time, maybe look at "topological sort" for DFS searches, although I may just be misunderstanding what you're asking.